# Semantic Web Framework

Tags: frameworks, semantic-web

What semantic web frameworks are there, and what are the advantages / disadvantages of each? I've made extensive use of [Jena](http://jena.sourceforge.net/), and I have looked at [Sesame](http://www.openrdf.org/) briefly. Are there others I should consider as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a more low-level appproach is [redland](http://librdf.org/), which provides bindings to a lot of languages like Perl, PHP, Python and Ruby. redland itself is written in C. i have scripted with it in ruby to provide a simple webservice with a rdf backend instead of a classic database.

Answer (score 7):

[Redland](http://librdf.org/) is a good RDF framework (just like Andreas said). I am mainly using its Python bindings and am installing it on Mac OS X via MacPorts (e.g., port install redland-bindings +python).

You could use it with other languages too (see its bindings for Perl, Ruby, ...).

For pointers to some larger lists of RDF frameworks see [Semantic Web FAQ: Tools](http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/SW-FAQ#tools).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cubicweb.org is a semantic web framework written in Python. It can be used to develop applications that serve content both to humans and computers, providing each with the format it asks for.

Answer (score 0):

This question may be related to [what-are-some-good-java-rdf-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73445/what-are-some-good-java-rdf-libraries)

Comment: That does seem to cover my question for the most part, I'll leave this one open though because I'm willing to investigate solutions outside of java.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely take a look at [Intellidimensions](http://www.intellidimension.com/) offerings if you are working on the Microsoft stack of technologies.

They have a mature SQL Server based framework for storing and processing (with rules) semantic web data.  They also have a great .NET SDK that I have used extensively.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java, and are interested in OWL inferencing, you should look at [Pellet](http://pellet.owldl.com).  It has bindings to Jena and the [OWL-API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/), which itself, is a useful semweb framework.

Answer (score 0):

The most web-centric I've seen so far is [RAP (RDF API for PHP).](http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/rdfapi/)