# Semantic web support for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, semantic-web

I'm doing a project and asp.net is one of my possible choices (the other one being php). I  need to implement some semantic functionality to improve searches.
I know some php frameworks support semantics but i want to know if asp.net has any[The most used] tool (3rd party or built in) that will also support this.

I've been reading more about this subject and i think what i'm really looking for is tools in order to deliver more accurate results to user searches by not only matching word but its meanings.

I'm sorry if the semantic web term caused confusion but my guide teacher called it like that

Comment: define semantics... like microformats or the new html-tags or?

Comment: or "sounds like" as in SQL Server?

Comment: consider asking on answers.semanticweb.com

Comment: can you maybe name some of the php frameworks you know so we have an idea what the .net counterpart could be?

Comment: @Pauli ARC, Powl are some php tools we have seen, as for a framework im pretty sure Drupal has rdf support

Comment: Since Powl's main focus is on RDF and OWL i'll recommend you look at ie. the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240903/what-is-a-good-rdf-library-for-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [dotNetRDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/) and [ARC PHP](https://github.com/semsol/arc2/wiki).

Other good resources

- [Executive’s Quick Start Guide to Web 3.0 and the Semantic Web](http://www.metadataaustralia2010.com/pdf/Mills%20Quickstart%20Guide.pdf)
- [RDF Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax/)
- [Wikipedia: Semantic Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web)
- [RDFa Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-rdfa-primer/)

That last one is about the recommended way to markup HTML with semantic meaning.  Improving your search results to include meaning can be done a number of ways and may or may not include using the semantic web technology stack per se.  Perhaps you only mean adding tags to blogs, or faceted searching such as that provided by SOLR.  You may need to clarify what kind of searching you want to do.

Comment: Just saw in here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83752/semantic-web-framework) about
Intellidimension, i think this tool besides the other options @harschware posted are a good enough start for comparing with our php options

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you need to clarify what you want to do, while you have clarified your question a little it is still not clear whether you actually need a full Semantic Web technology stack.

Your project may be completely doable without any Semantic Web tech just using standard text indexing systems like Lucene and SOLR.  I'm fairly sure both of these are available in .Net, I'm not a PHP developer myself so not sure if there are usable PHP equivalents.

If you need a full Semantic Web technology stack then either of the options harschware has suggested are good (*disclaimer - I develop dotNetRDF*).  Whether they actually do what you need them to do depends on what parts of the Semantic Web technology stack you need.  Both have good RDF and SPARQL support but minimal OWL support.

Comment: as i said before i asked about semantic web because it was the concept our guide teacher used. I'll get another look with my teammates, and also get some feedback from our teacher.

Thanks for your remarks about using Lucene and SOLR.

Answer (score -1):

"Semantic Web" just means using the appropriate html tags for their defined (semantic)  purpose.  This is accomplished by not ignoring less-used tags (label, legend, fieldset, cite, etc), using table only for tabular data, and especially not using div or span when more-specific tags are really a better fit... things like that.

With this in mind, of course asp.net supports a semantic web.  You can put any html you want into asp.net pages.  MVC makes this easier, but you can do it with webforms, too.

With that constraint out of the way, my standard advice when beginning a new project is to start with what you know.  If you already know php or asp.net, stick with that.  It will allow you to be a lot more productive, more responsive to issues, and make fewer mistakes than you will if you're learning a new platform from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification about semantic web, i've edited my question because is not what i really meant.
This project is in 5-man groups so, in general, we have experience in  both asp.net and php platforms and we're just trying to decide which one will give us the best tools

Comment: I'm not sure wikipedia agrees with your concept of Semantic Web http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web

Comment: I agree with @harschware here, you seem to be conflating the Semantic web with Semantic HTML http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML While there is some crossover if you are going to use RDFa to embed RDF in your HTML the Semantic Web represents a much broader technology stack than what you have implied