# Web semantic Frameworks

Tags: node.js, sparql, rdf, semantic-web, rdfs

I searched a lot for web semantic frameworks, I found some results in [w3c docs](https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/wiki/SemanticWebTools#JavaScript_Developers)
but I think that the most mentionned frameworks are outdated specially when I click on some frameworks they give me invalid URL.
The question was asked in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83752/semantic-web-framework) but it was 13 years ago.
also I found that the main framework using java language is Apache Jena.

I am searching for semantic web frameworks or libraries (which are still used) in other languages: Javascript (with Node), Python (Django), Php, Kotlin ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "web semantic framework"?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @jfriend00
Thanks for your comment what I meant was: 
For Javascript: lets suppose that we are using node js for backend: how to store rdf, use rdfs and create queries with sparql in node js 
For Python: how to store rdf, use rdfs and create queries with sparql in Django.
for php: how to store rdf, use rdfs and create queries with sparql in Laravel.....

Comment: I'd suggest you rework your question to describe exactly what you are looking for with more specificity (incorporating everything you have in that comment) because asking for a "web semantic framework" is far too undefined and broad.

Comment: It also appears that you're discovering that the once heralded RDF format is not being used all that often any more.  So, it might also be interesting for you to describe what you're really trying to build and perhaps people can point you in a different direction.

Comment: Python: rdflib -- it is the top search hit for "python rdf". RDF toolkits in other languages can be similarly found. Look for "triplestores" for RDF databases.

Comment: @jfriend00
I am trying to build search engine and the data is stored using RDF, what they are using nowadays ?

Comment: @AndyS
I am new in this domain after hours of searching I found 
[this](https://zazuko.com/get-started/developers/?fbclid=IwAR3hPqe-t87_NnBXLySgDJ82VEUIAmEoDEp5bVguZNLsK1IozFhZPenr5J8) for javascript

, jena for java
and like you said rdflib for python 
Can you tell me, what's the best relevant technology which is recommended to use in this field (widely used, more tutorials ...)?

Comment: RDF is being used. Enough to sustain growing companies and software consultants. Look for "Knowledge Graphs". It is required format in some place (being non-proprietary). Wiki pages (for all technologies) often fall out of date - easier to write than maintain!

Comment: StackOverflow does not encourage recommendations of systems or technologies.

Comment: If your goal is to search through RDF triples, I think you can put them into a triple store (database) and just use SPARQL queries for search. Alternatively, you may convert your RDF data to XML or JSON and feed them into some document search engine.